# Invalid input crashing the program. Is there a way to ignore it?

Tags: c++

My code is meant to allow a user to input a number 0-9 and out that number as a string. i.e. 1 = "one". Pressing Ctrl + D exits the code. Here it is for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    while ( !cin.eof() ) {
        cin >> num;
        switch(num) {
            case 0 :
                cout << "zero" << endl; 
                break;
            case 1 :
                cout << "one" << endl; 
                break;
            case 2 :
                cout << "two" << endl; 
                break;
            case 3 :
                cout << "three" << endl; 
                break;
            case 4 :
                cout << "four" << endl; 
                break;
            case 5 :
                cout << "five" << endl; 
                break;
            case 6 :
                cout << "six" << endl; 
                break;
            case 7 :
                cout << "seven" << endl; 
                break;
            case 8 :
                cout << "eight" << endl; 
                break;
            case 9 :
                cout << "nine" << endl; 
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I input the correct integers, the code behaves as it should. If input a double digit integer like 10, the code just ignores it, which is fine. However if I put in a non-int like "i", "f" or "cat" the program spams "zero" repeatedly and Ctrl + D no longer works to end the program.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to set it so inputting non-ints would behave the same way as inputting double digit ints? If not, is there a way to only allow cin to take in integers? Thanks!

Comment: [why `while (!cin.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Other than checking for `eof()` - which is bad enough - the only direct interaction you have with `cin` in your loop is `cin >> num` which, if the user enters anything that cannot be interpreted as an integral value, sets the stream to a fail state AND leaves the unexpected input in the stream - so it will be read again.   Why would you expect anything other than the behaviour you're seeing?   Anyway, try reading characters directly from the stream into a string (which will accept any valid characters the user types) and then parse the strings.

Answer (score 0):

At an invalid input, `cin >> num` is stuck. You need to reset the stream to "good state" and clear the bad input.

It's also recommended that you check for EOF immediately after attempt to input.

```
while ( true ) {
    cin >> num;
    if ( cin.eof() ) break;
    if ( !cin ) {
        cerr << "Bad input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    switch(num) {
        case /* your code ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: After the input? How does that work? If I do that, how does the program allow the user a chance to break it? Right now it allows input/break and then gives an output before giving the user another chance to input break. But if I had it check after the input, wouldn't the window of time between output and more requested input be too small to break from?

Comment: @Zevvysan The functionality remains unchanged. If the user enters `aasdadadafafa`, it complains about bad input. If the user gives EOF, then it quits. Maybe you didn't understand the code?